# how to initialize array using type.NewArray in golang?

Tags: arrays, go

Basically, I want to use the Array type struct in the `types` module but I'm unable to initialize it. What do you have to pass in the Type as the first argument?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/types"
)

func main() {
    var a *types.Array
    a = types.NewArray(types.Int, 2) //error here
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Comment: Please [take the Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) to get the basics of the language down.

Comment: You need to pass a value of a type that implements the `types.Type` interface, what you're doing is passing a value of type `types.BasicKind`, but this type does not implement that interface, therefore you cannot pass it in as the first argument to `types.NewArray`.

Comment: @Adrian are you sure Go tour covers go/types package??

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/#Type documentation says `All types implement the Type interface.` in this context it sounds that `int` is not type weird...

Comment: @mkopriva could you please provide an example?? https://play.golang.org/p/UIQi6sgGVA or anyone, instead of just downvoting

Comment: finally I figured it out https://play.golang.org/p/fP112xqFp6

Comment: @SagarShah: what are you trying to do? The `go/types` package doesn't do much on its own, and is definitely not something someone "very new to go" would be venturing into.

Comment: @DanielGrankin by "all types" they mean types defined in that package, and it's just a generalization since `BasicKind`, a type also defined in that package, does not implement that interface.

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva it would be great if they explain what they mean :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new in go. And for me the question doesn't look stupid. Unfortunately no one has explained how to use NewArray yet. It seems to me that golang community is not very friendly I've met more downvoting than real help for now.

Btw I took course of Go tour :) But anyway I was confused that question how to get type of an object bring you to `reflect package` usually (type in google something like `golang get type of an object`) which has nothing in common with `types.Type`. I spent some time to figure out how to get `types.Type` object, and it's not obvious I think for people who has experience in other languages.

So to use `NewArray` method you neeed to pass an object which implements `types.Type` as mkopriva pointed. I end up with

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/types"
)

type NewType int

func (v NewType) String() string {
    return string(v)
}

func (v NewType) Underlying() types.Type {
    return types.Type(v)
}

func main() {
    var a *types.Array
    a = types.NewArray(NewType(0), 2)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

There is used new type with underlying `int`. I guess I don't understand something yet in golang since for using such simple thing I had to write such useless methods as `String` and `Underlying`, they are useless because of implementation, I don't see the reason to be forced write such code. I appriciate if golang experts explain this stuff!

Comment: Package `go/types`, and all its sibling packages under the `go/` parent are there to help you work with Go source code, analyzation, type checking, parsing, etc. `NewArray` is not meant to be used as an initializer for arrays that you use in your typical app.

Comment: That is the reason the OP was referred to the Go tour, stuff under `go/` is generally for advanced users of the Go language, those that are familiar with the basics, not those that are just learning the basics.

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you!!! When I saw the question I though hm I've taken go tour but don't know answer. Unfortunately first comments were not very helpful and I decided to figure out what is NewArray on my own and I got working example but had no idea why I need it, so thank you for explaining :)

Comment: If someone wants to initialize a slice or an array in Go they can do so with `make([]T, len, cap)` (for slices), or `var arr [N]T` (for arrays).

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to find info how to create slice, array, but as for type.NewArray seems not :)

Comment: It's good practice to read a package's documentation in case you're unsure what one of its functions/types is supposed to be used for. `go/types` is pretty clear about its objective right in the first paragraph. That said, I do find OPs confusion only natural and think that downvoting them is unhelpful and counterproductive.

Comment: @mkopriva Then how should I add an array as a struct member if I do not know what the length is going to be??

Comment: @SagarShah you can use a slice, which is just like an array but has dynamic length. In Go arrays are used very little, most of the time you should use a slice. A slice initialized like this `var S []T`, or `S := []T{}`, or `make([]T, len, cap)` can be grown by using `append`.

Comment: @SagarShah here are a couple examples https://play.golang.org/p/3EQRMXpIWL

Comment: @mkopriva but that is a slice and not an array. i actually wanted to use my struct as a key in a map and it fails if it has an slice member. That is why I wanted an array member. But thank you for the help..

Comment: @SagarShah fair enough, but in Go you cannot have an array without first knowing its length because the *length is part of the type*. What you want is basically not supported by the language so you need to rethink the design of you map.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks. Your latest comment has completely answered my question. I will have to redesign my approach. I think I have overused tuples as keys in dicts because i come from a python background